# how to install conky manager package

Tags: package-management, conky

I can't get download conky manager package...
It's forbidden for me..
I tried to download and remove later but conky window can't remove...
[I can't remove this part from my screen by uninstalling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwcns.png)

Comment: Did you try running `pkill conky` from your terminal? What happens if you do?